# Displaying all running apps in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, background

Hey, I was wondering how I could make my app getting info about which apps that are currenly running on the mac. So I basiclly want to get the same information as the force quit does (Apple Logo > Force Quit)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`-[NSWorkspace launchedApplications]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html).